# Latest 0.39.1 version does not allow accessing objects without listing the directory content before

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

Our servers restart nightly and we noticed that as of yesterday (with the release of 0.39.1) our servers did not properly start up anymore.

We noticed that when we try to access files on a bucket (mounted through gcsfuse) - we get access denied / file not found errors.
So for example the following structure:

(BUCKET)

-(DIR)

--FILE_A

cp /dir/file_a /tmp --> File not found

ls /dir/file_a --> not found

ls /dir
-- shows FILE_A as part of the directory content

We first need to run the "ls" command inside the subdirectory, where the file is located - only then can we see file_a.
If we run the same cp command after listing the directories content, immediately again - then it works fine.

cp /dir/file_a /tmp --> Success

For some odd reason, we can only access a file, once we have done a "ls" in the directory beforehand.

I reverted back to 0.38.0 and there it works fine?!

Is this an issue on our side?

Comment: Could you repeat the same using the below flags for the current version
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs --foreground --debug_fs --debug_gcs --debug_fuse <mount_point>
Tried to repro with 0.40 and seems to work.